# Wrong position received with triangulation in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, triangulation

This is somewhat broad, but here we go: I've a very strange problem occurring with my triangulation algorithm. Sometimes, it returns the correct latitude/longitude, and then, after some time, it returns wrong latitude/longitude. More strange is that I can't predict when this error gonna happen, neither reproduce it. It occurs even if I don't change lines in my code (receive correct values, then wrong, then correct, and so on...).

I'm using google GLM service, sending the device LAC (location area code) and the Tower ID to triangle my position. The core method of my algorithm is in follow:

```
private double[] getPositionByTriangle(int lac, int cid) {
    int shortcid = cid & 0xffff;
    double location[] = new double[2];
    try {
        String surl = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(surl);
        httppost.setEntity(new CellIDRequestEntity(shortcid, lac));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(entity.getContent());
        // Read some prior data
        dis.readShort();
        dis.readByte();
        // Read the error-code
        int errorCode = dis.readInt();
        if (errorCode == 0) {
            location[0] = (double) dis.readInt() / 1000000D;
            location[1] = (double) dis.readInt() / 1000000D;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return location;
}
```

**Extra info, that maybe can be of some help**: This method is used in a class that extends Android Service, called with a delay of 1 minute through PendingIntent. The thread that calls it saves the lat/lon values in SharedPreferences, and then I use it in all my views.

I'm wondering if I've implemented the method with wrong algorithm or if there's a trick in the proccess that I've missed. Currently, my correct aproximated lat/lon values are **latitude = -23** and **longitude = -46**, but I'm receiving (sometimes) the values of **latitude = 17** and **longitude = 81**. Can someone give me a hint on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I've found the solution on my own. Here we go.
The triangulation proccess is basically a three-argument combination proccess. Based in some searches I've done, I deduce that you can use different types of combinations of data. The combination that I've used is a mix with tower ID (the tower transciever that the device is handshaked), the location codes (area code and country code) and the location area code. So, my new code looks like the following:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();
location = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
networkOperator = tm.getNetworkOperator();
cellID = location.getCid();
lac = location.getLac();

public double[] getLocationByMCCMNC(String mcc, String mnc, String lac, String cellId, boolean requestAddress) throws IOException {

    final String data = "{\"cell_towers\": [{\"location_area_code\": \""
        + lac + "\", \"mobile_network_code\": \"" + mnc
        + "\", \"cell_id\": \"" + cellId
        + "\", \"mobile_country_code\": \"" + mcc
        + "\"}], \"version\": \"1.1.0\", \"request_address\": \""
        + requestAddress + "\"}";

    URL anUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/loc/json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) anUrl.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/jsonrequest");

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data.getBytes());
    out.close();

    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = reader.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        builder.append(String.valueOf(buf, 0, read));
    }
    in.close();
    conn.disconnect();

    double location[] = new double[2];
    try {
        JSONObject loc = new JSONObject(builder.toString()).getJSONObject("location");
        location[0] = Double.valueOf(loc.getDouble("latitude"));
        location[1] = Double.valueOf(loc.getDouble("longitude"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        location[0] = -1;
    location[1] = -1;
    }
    return location;
}
```

With this new code, note that I was using Google Location JSON service, that returns a JSON object. I should say that this is a very trick issue and I'm in need to search even more to understand all the mechams, but at least, this is a working code. Hope that it helps someone.

**UPDATE: I also like to complete this answer in the following context: TRIANGULATION USES RADIO ACCESS THROUGH MOBILE NETWORK (GSM, UMTS, LTE, AND SO ON). I'M PRETTY SURE NOW THAT THESE VALUE FLUTUATIONS COMES FROM THE FACT THAT RADIO WAVES HAVE MUCH INTERFERENCE OVER THE ENVIRONMENT (WALLS, BUILDINGS, NEIGHBORING TOWERS, ETC)**